# Set the div id dynamically to a variable and use it for hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to this .Net and I need to get the `div` `id` dynamically to set it to a variable and use it later when hovering.

In my case I have 4 `div` elements namely `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, `div4` and inside those divs I have four images with id `pic1`, `pic2`, `pic3`, `pic4`. So when I hover on any one of those the image inside that div should animate.

How can I get the div id in a variable when hovering and use that to animate that specific image.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#div1").hover(function() { 
        $("#pic1").animate({ width: '150px', height: '150px' }); 
    }); 
    $("#div2").hover(function() { 
        $("#pic2").animate({ width: '150px', height: '150px' }); 
    }); 
});
```

Please can any one help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: Did u try anything...can u post some code dat you tried?

Comment: You say .Net, but later you refer to HTML elements (div). What does .Net have to to with that - do you work on a webapp thats written in some .Net language?

Comment: Incremental ids or classes always lead to a maintenance nightmare. Use a generic class instead, and traverse the DOM to get the related element to display. This construct will work for any amount of div groups, without any maintenance.

Comment: Could use .Net coding or only JavaScript ?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#div1").hover(function() {
              $("#pic1").animate({ width: '150px', height: '150px' });
          });

          $("#div2").hover(function() {
              $("#pic2").animate({ width: '150px', height: '150px' });
          });
          });
Here i have used two functions but in my case i need to write a single function and i need to get the div id dynamically when hover..

Comment: @til_b for your information .NET too uses html forms and all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').hover(function(){
  $('#'+this.id).children("img").animate({/*animation options*/});
});
```

Comment: here in your code we need to specify the div id as the selector.but i need this selector to be generated dynamically when hover on a div.

Comment: No, `$("div")` will select all divs, whereas `$("#divid")` will select by ID. See http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ .

Comment: Thanks i got the div id but couldnt animate the image because each image has different id.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function onover()
{

  var divid = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  // divid is the id of the div

}
```

call this function on mouse over event of the pics and do whatever

Answer (score 1):

If the image is in the div you want to listen for mouseover events on, you could just call the elements child using `find()` in jQuery. Example:

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="imagecontainer">
    <img id="pic1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png" />
</div>
<div id="div2" class="imagecontainer">
    <img id="pic2" src="http://foo.com/bar2.png" />
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(".imagecontainer").mouseover(function(event) {
    $(this).find("img").animate(/*animation here*/);
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

html code

```
<ul>
<li id="1"></li>    
<li id="2"></li>
<li id="3"></li>
<li id="4"></li>    
<li id="5"></li>
<li id="6"></li>
<ul>
```

jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('li').mouseover(function(){
divId = $(this).attr('id');
$("#pic"+divId).animate({ width: '150px', height: '150px' }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').mouseover(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$("pic"+id).animate(do your stuff here);
});
```